# Use Arrow schema with parquet StreamWriter

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I am attempting to use the C++ `StreamWriter` class provided by Apache Arrow.

The only example of using `StreamWriter` uses the low-level Parquet API i.e.

```
parquet::schema::NodeVector fields;

fields.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make(
  "string_field", parquet::Repetition::OPTIONAL, parquet::Type::BYTE_ARRAY,
  parquet::ConvertedType::UTF8));

fields.push_back(parquet::schema::PrimitiveNode::Make(
   "char_field", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, parquet::Type::FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY,
   parquet::ConvertedType::NONE, 1));

auto node = std::static_pointer_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode>(
   parquet::schema::GroupNode::Make("schema", parquet::Repetition::REQUIRED, fields));
```

The end result is a `std::shared_ptr<parquet::schema::GroupNode>` that can then be passed into `StreamWriter`.

**Is it possible to construct and use "high-level" Arrow schemas with `StreamWriter`**? They are supported when using the `WriteTable` function (non-streaming) but I've found no examples of its use with the streaming API.

I, of course, can resort to using the low-level API but it is extremely verbose when creating large and complicated schema and I would prefer (but not need) to use the high-level Arrow schema mechanisms.

For example,

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile_;
PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(outfile_, arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open("test.parquet"));

// construct an arrow schema
auto schema = arrow::schema({arrow::field("field1", arrow::int64()),
                                   arrow::field("field2", arrow::float64()),
                                   arrow::field("field3", arrow::float64())});

// build the writer properties
parquet::WriterProperties::Builder builder;
auto properties = builder.build()

// my current best attempt at converting the Arrow schema to a Parquet schema
std::shared_ptr<parquet::SchemaDescriptor> parquet_schema;
parquet::arrow::ToParquetSchema(schema.get(), *properties, &parquet_schema); // parquet_schema is now populated

// and now I try and build the writer - this fails
auto writer = parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(outfile_, parquet_schema->group_node(), properties);
```

The last line fails because `parquet_schema->group_node()` (which is the only way I'm aware of to get access to the `GroupNode` for the schema) returns a `const GroupNode*` whereas `ParquetFileWriter::Open)` needs a `std::shared_ptr<GroupNode>`.

I'm not sure casting-away the constness of the returned group node and forcing it into the `::Open()` call is an officially supported (or correct) usage of `StreamWriter`.

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use low-level api for StreamWriter.

a very tricky way:

```
auto writer = parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(outfile_, std::shared_ptr<parquet::schema::GroupNode>(const_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode *>(parquet_schema->group_node())), properties);
```

you may need to converter schema manually.

source code  `cpp/src/parquet/arrow/schema.cc` may help you.

```
PARQUET_EXPORT
::arrow::Status ToParquetSchema(const ::arrow::Schema* arrow_schema,
                                const WriterProperties& properties,
                                std::shared_ptr<SchemaDescriptor>* out);
```